# Using QPainter to draw a line between QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

I'm working on an application where I need to be able to draw a line between two `QWidget` objects. I have tried quite a few things, but my current attempt (which I *think* is in the right direction I just think I'm missing something) is to have the containing widget (which I called `DrawWidget` and which holds the `QGridLayout` that the `QWidget` objects are added to) override the `paintEvent` method and call the `QPainter::drawLine()` function.

The issues I'm having are that:

1. No matter how I try to get the position of the widgets, the endpoints of the line are always in the wrong place
2. Whenever I try to draw a second line, the first line that I drew gets erased.

Here is the `paintEvent` function of the containing widget:

```
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    if (!drewSinceUpdate){
        drewSinceUpdate = true;
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black));

        painter.drawLine(start->geometry().center(), end->geometry().center());
    }
}
```

I have tried many different ways to get the correct position of the widgets in the last line of `paintEvent`, which I will post some of the ways (I can't remember all of them):

```
painter.drawLine(start->pos(), end->pos());
painter.drawLine(start->mapToGlobal(start->geometry().center()), end->mapToGlobal(end->geometry().center()));
painter.drawLine(this->mapToGlobal(start->geometry().center()), this->mapToGlobal(end->geometry().center()));
painter.drawLine(start->mapTo(this, start->pos()), end->mapTo(this, end->pos()));
painter.drawLine(this->mapFrom(start, start->pos()), this->mapFrom(end, end->pos()));
```

And just to make my question clear, here is an example of what I am looking for, taken from [QT Diagram Scene Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html):
[image: Example of what I want]
But this is what I end up getting:

[image: What I get]
Thank you for any help you can provide.

NOTE:

-`start` and `end` are both `QWidget` objects which I passed in using another method

-The hierarchy relevant to `DrawWidget` is:

```
QMainWindow
->QScrollArea
  ->DrawWidget
    ->QGridLayout
      ->Items       <-- These are the things I want to connect
```

EDIT: To make a Complete and Verifiable example, here is the entirety of the relevant code.

MainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollBar>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // Setting up the relevant hierarchy 
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);

    drawWidget = new DrawWidget();
    gridLayout = new QGridLayout();
    gridLayout->setSpacing(300);
    drawWidget->setLayout(gridLayout);

    scrollArea->setWidget(drawWidget);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    AddItemSlot();

    QApplication::connect(scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar(), SIGNAL(rangeChanged(int,int)), this, SLOT(scrollHorizontal()));
}

// This is just creating a single one of the example widgets which I want to connect
QWidget* MainWindow::CreateNewItem(){
    QWidget* itemWidget = new QWidget();
    itemWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: lightgray");
    QHBoxLayout* singleItemLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    itemWidget->setLayout(singleItemLayout);

    QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(std::to_string(counter++).c_str());
    textEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color:white;");
    singleItemLayout->addWidget(textEdit);

    QVBoxLayout* rightSidePanel = new QVBoxLayout();
    rightSidePanel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

    QPushButton* button1 = new QPushButton("Top Button");

    QApplication::connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(AddItemSlot()));

    rightSidePanel->addWidget(button1);

    QWidget* rightPanelWidget = new QWidget();
    rightSidePanel->setMargin(0);
    rightPanelWidget->setLayout(rightSidePanel);

    singleItemLayout->addWidget(rightPanelWidget);

    itemWidget->setLayout(singleItemLayout);
    itemWidget->setMinimumWidth(400);
    itemWidget->setFixedSize(400,200);

    return itemWidget;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::scrollHorizontal()
{
    scrollArea->ensureWidgetVisible(noteItems.back());
}

void MainWindow::AddItemSlot()
{
    QWidget* w = CreateNewItem();
    gridLayout->addWidget(w,currRow, currCol++);
    if (!noteItems.empty()){
        drawWidget->updateEndpoints(noteItems.back(), w);
    }
    noteItems.push_back(w);
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <drawwidget.h>
#include "drawscrollarea.h"
#include <vector>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void scrollHorizontal();
    void AddItemSlot();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QWidget* CreateNewItem();
    int counter = 0, currCol = 0, currRow = 0;
    std::vector<QWidget*> noteItems;

    QScrollArea* scrollArea;
    DrawWidget* drawWidget;
    QGridLayout* gridLayout;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

DrawWidget.cpp:

```
#include "drawwidget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRect>

DrawWidget::DrawWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

void DrawWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    if (!drewSinceUpdate){
        drewSinceUpdate = true;
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black));

        for (ConnectedPair pair : items){
            const QWidget* from = pair.from;
            const QWidget* to =pair.to;

            QPoint start =  from->mapToGlobal(from->rect().topRight() +  QPoint(0, from->height()/2));
            QPoint end = to->mapToGlobal(to->rect().topLeft() +  QPoint(0, to->height()/2));

            painter.drawLine(mapFromGlobal(start), mapFromGlobal(end));
        }
    }
}

void DrawWidget::updateEndpoints(QWidget* startIn, QWidget* endIn){
    drewSinceUpdate = false;
    items.push_back(ConnectedPair{startIn, endIn});
}
```

DrawWidget.h

```
#ifndef DRAWWIDGET_H
#define DRAWWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtCore>
#include <vector>

class DrawWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DrawWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void updateEndpoints(QWidget* startIn, QWidget* endIn);
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
signals:

private:
    struct ConnectedPair {
        const QWidget* from;
        const QWidget* to;
    };

    std::vector<ConnectedPair> items;
    bool drewSinceUpdate = true;
};

#endif // DRAWWIDGET_H
```

Comment: How do you choose which widgets you are going to connect with the arrows?

Comment: You need to show a more complete example.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You tried with my solution?

Comment: You must call `update()` in an updateEndpoints function to call the paintEvent method

Comment: Awesome thank works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Ahh I spoke too soon. So it works until the scrollArea becomes scrollable. However, once I add enough widgets to the point where a scrollbar shows up, no lines are being drawn. I tried calling `update()` in my `scrollHorizontal()` slot, but it still won't draw.

Comment: What do you use `drewSinceUpdate`?

Comment: This variable is causing the problem, what happens is that every time you resize, move the widget, etc, the widget will call paintEvent and redraw it, but in your case can not do it for that variable.

Comment: I didn't want to unnecessarily being redrawing already drawn lines, but I see I had a lack of understanding of how the `paintEvent()` method worked, because as soon as I removed that check with `drewSinceUpdate` it worked. Thank you so much for your help, I'm accepting your answer!

Comment: The task of painting a line does not consume time, the tasks that can consume time are mathematical calculations, QPainter is optimized for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case we use the function [mapToGlobal()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) and [mapfromGlobal()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapFromGlobal), since pos() returns a position with respect to the parent and this can cause problems if the widget has different parents.

**drawwidget.h**

```
#ifndef DRAWWIDGET_H
#define DRAWWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class DrawWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DrawWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void addWidgets(const QWidget *from, const QWidget *to);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

private:
    struct WidgetsConnected {
        const QWidget* from;
        const QWidget* to;
    };

    QList<WidgetsConnected> list;

};

#endif // DRAWWIDGET_H
```

**drawwidget.cpp**

```
#include "drawwidget.h"

#include <QPainter>
DrawWidget::DrawWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void DrawWidget::addWidgets(const QWidget * from, const QWidget * to)
{
    list.append(WidgetsConnected{from , to});
    update();
}

void DrawWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    for(const WidgetsConnected el: list){
        const QWidget* from = el.from;
        const QWidget* to = el.to;

        QPoint start =  from->mapToGlobal(from->rect().topRight() +  QPoint(0, from->height()/2));
        QPoint end = to->mapToGlobal(to->rect().topLeft() +  QPoint(0, to->height()/2));

        painter.drawLine(mapFromGlobal(start), mapFromGlobal(end));
    }
}
```

<sub>The complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/45319476).</sub>

[image]

Comment: eyllanesc, thanks for the help. I tried what you suggested, and while it *did* center it vertically, the horizontal location of the endpoints is still kind of just floating in the middle of nowhere (like the picture I posted). Any idea why?

Comment: Right now I'm going to try out your code, I see you include this `drawscrollarea.h` library, but I do not see any statement, is it typo?

Comment: It was an attempt to fix this issue by subclassing QScrollArea...it didn't work I just forgot to remove the include.