# How to draw line behind buttons in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt5, qwidget

## Question

In a custom widget, I'd like to draw lines (using `QPainter`) that connect buttons in a `QGridLayout`. The lines shall be behind the buttons, in order to

- a) not interfere with buttons in between
- b) allow starting the lines in the center of the buttons, not the edges

Considering ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319476/using-qpainter-to-draw-a-line-between-qwidgets), I could almost realize a simple, basic version running in my GUI application (source code below).

As long as I use `QPushButton` with the standard Qt style, it works like a charm (left), but, as I want to use a custom style, the lines overlap (right):

[image: Qt style buttons]  [image: Custom style buttons]

What property or mechanism is causing this behavior?

---

## Code

MyFrame.h:

```
#include <QFrame>

class MyFrame : public QFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame();
    virtual ~MyFrame() = default;
};
```

MyFrame.cpp:

```
#include "MyFrame.h"

#include "LineDrawWidget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QButtonGroup>

MyFrame::MyFrame()
{
    auto* mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    auto* buttonLayout = new QGridLayout();

    QPushButton* button;
    auto* buttons = new QButtonGroup();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        button = new QPushButton();
        button->setText(QString::number(i+1));
        button->setFixedHeight(40);
        button->setFixedWidth(40);
        button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color : black; background-color : white; }");
        button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { border-style : outset; border-color: black; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 6px; }");
        buttonLayout->addWidget(button);
        buttons->addButton(button, i);
    }

    auto* lineDraw = new LineDrawWidget(
            buttons->button(0),
            buttons->button(2));
    lineDraw->setLayout(buttonLayout);
    mainLayout->addWidget(lineDraw);
}
```

LineDrawWidget.h:

```
#include <QWidget>

class LineDrawWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    LineDrawWidget(
            QWidget* from,
            QWidget* to,
            QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    virtual ~LineDrawWidget() = default;

protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e) final override;

private:
    QWidget* _from;
    QWidget* _to;
};
```

LineDrawWidget.cpp:

```
#include "LineDrawWidget.h"

#include <QPainter>

LineDrawWidget::LineDrawWidget(
        QWidget* from,
        QWidget* to,
        QWidget* parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        _from(from),
        _to(to)
{

}

void LineDrawWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
    (void)e;

    QPainter painter(this);

    QPoint start =  _from->mapToGlobal(_from->rect().bottomLeft());
    QPoint end = _to->mapToGlobal(_to->rect().topRight());
    painter.drawLine(mapFromGlobal(start), mapFromGlobal(end));
}
```

Comment: Not directly related: `Q_UNUSED(e);` instead of `(void)e;` would be more readable.

Comment: @Azeem thanks for the input, didn't know this one yet.

Comment: You are welcome! :) See: [Q_UNUSED](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_UNUSED)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the two separate calls to `setStyle` for a single `QPushButton` -- the second call appears to reset all properties not present in it.  Try putting it all in a single call...

```
button->setStyleSheet("color : black; background-color : white; border-style : outset; border-color: black; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 6px;");
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: As simple as it gets.. Works for me as well, thank you!